# Unable to install Git-core+svn by MacPorts

Tags: git, svn, installation, macports

I am trying to install Git-core with svn to my Mac unsuccessfully by

```
$ sudo port install git-core +svn
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for db46
Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for patch.4.6.21.3
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: p5-svn-simple subversion-perlbindings apr-util db46 sqlite3 cyrus-sasl2 neon serf subversion p5-term-readkey
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

I have tried to solve the problem unsuccessfully by

```
sudo port -f clean --all {neon, subversion,...}
```

How can you solve the problem?

**Solved:**

A program called Peerguardian blocked the installation. When I removed it, everything works now. Great thanks to all repliers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing because there was an error building `db46`; specifically, there was a problem in checksumming the patch files that were downloaded by the `port` utility. It looks like it may be an issue with the port, but I just built `db46` without any problem. Have you updated your ports tree recently? You can try doing this:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate               # updates the ports tree and port utility
$ sudo port install git +svn    # installs git
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? It could be blocking the port over which rsync communicates (port uses rsync for updating). Or maybe the server was experiencing problems. Try it again; if it still fails, run port with the -d option to get debug output.

Comment: I tested without a firewall, the same error. The error with debugging is at http://dpaste.com/35744/

Comment: There's at least one ticket that suggests that you may need to clean your ports tree before updating (for some reason). You can do that with $ sudo port clean --all installed.

Comment: mipadi: Thank you! Your tip saved me.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle recently silently changed their patch so the checksums do not match.  That's been fixed in MacPorts, so if you self update, then it'll work correctly.