# How can I continue an interrupted installation with MacPorts?

Tags: unix, macports

I'm new to all things shell/binary, and was installing Git (I understand SCM is a good thing from being on SO). My Internet connection hiccuped partway through, however, and the installation stalled.

It interrupted a tar.gz download, and I don't know quite how to resume where it left off. Here's the output:

```
computer:~ Alex$ sudo port install git-core +svn+bash_completion
--->  Computing dependencies for git-core
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for p5-error
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Could not open file: 
/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/perl5/Error-0.17015.tar.gz
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: p5-error p5-libwww-perl p5-crypt-ssleay
    p5-html-parser p5-html-tagset p5-io-compress p5-compress-raw-bzip2 p5-compress-raw-zlib
    p5-uri p5-svn-simple subversion-perlbindings apr apr-util db46 cyrus-sasl2 gettext neon
    serf subversion p5-term-readkey rsync popt
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
computer:~ Alex$
```

So I tried twice, no luck. I found that file and replaced it with a complete file downloaded from the referenced website, and tried again; no luck. Can someone tell me how I might resume this process? I'm not sure quite how to tell it to pickup again.

Comment: Does this help any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765959/unable-to-install-git-coresvn-by-macports

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean the perl5 and p5-error ports:

```
sudo port clean perl5 p5-error
```

Then

```
sudo port sync
```

to make sure your `port` configuration is up-to-date.

Then retry the original port command to install `git`.

If that doesn't work do a:

```
sudo port clean all
```

and retry.

Comment: `port sync` will not upgrade MacPorts.  You should use `port selfupdate` by default.

Comment: That's true but although the base MacPorts system and tools aren't upgraded very often.  The ports trees are updated all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean the distribution file:

```
`sudo port clean --dist p5-error`
```

Incidentally, clean --all would also be a flag that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the port first

```
sudo port clean git-core
```

Then reinstall

Comment: Cleaning unfortunately didn't help and the same error comes up. Thanks though.

Comment: Ned Daily's answer is better try cleaning the task that failed ie perl5